# gitignore - ignore generated files in a folder, but not the folder

Tags: git, github, gulp

I have a gulp task that pipes assets into a directory. I would like to include the directory in my project, but **exclude** the outputted files through a `.gitignore` file. My gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass('app/scss/styles.scss')
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/stylesheets'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('app/js/script.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Folder structure:

```
app
---js
---scss
public(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
---javascripts(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
-----scrpits.min.js**(NEED TO IGNORE THIS)**
---stylesheets(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
-----styles.css**(NEED TO IGNORE THIS)**
```

So in `.gitignore` if I go:

`/public`

That ignores everything, which is not what I want.

I found this question: [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) and someone suggested a "workaround" with 54 upvotes:

> "Andy Lester is right, but if your directory just needs to be empty,
>   and not empty empty, you can put an empty .gitignore file in there as
>   a workaround..."

So now I go:

```
app
---js
---scss
public(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
---javascripts(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
-----scrpits.min.js**(NEED TO IGNORE THIS)**
-----.gitignore
---stylesheets(NEED TO KEEP THIS)
-----styles.css**(NEED TO IGNORE THIS)**
-----.gitignore
```

And took a suggestion from the accepted answer and did:

`/public/!.gitignore`

But still is not getting the desired result.

How can I commit an output folder to a repository for a gulp task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

```
/public/**/*.js
/public/**/*.css
```

Essentially, any file in any folder below one level in /public should be ignored.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I will tag as accepted as soon as I can

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't store directories (aka folders) at all, it only stores files within a commit.  When Git goes to check out a commit, if some file within that commit requires that some parent directory exist, Git makes that parent directory at that point.  So that's why you need to commit the file `.gitignore`, or anyway *some* file, within the directory: so that Git has some file it's extracting, that forces it to *create* the directory.

Now, the problem here is that when Git is doing its "run as fast as possible even if that confuses everyone" :-) tricks, it may discover that a `.gitignore` lists a directory name *and* that it—specifically, Git's *index*—has no files *already* within that directory, and it will then not even bother to *look inside* the directory for files.  This is how `git add` skips right over the `!public/.gitignore` directive: while it was looking around, it found `public` as a directory but had no files in it to be committed yet, then found `public` in `.gitignore`, and decided *not to look inside* `public` at all.

If, instead of listing `public` in your `.gitignore`, you list `public/*`, Git has to look inside `public` to find all its files and sub-directories to see if they can be skipped.  Having looked inside, it will check `public/.gitignore` against the `.gitignore` contents.  The `public/*` entry will say "skip it" but the later `!public/.gitignore` entry will say "don't skip it".  The later entry then overrides, and `public/.gitignore` gets stuffed into Git's index by `git add --all` or `git commit --all`.

Once `public/.gitignore` is in the index, it goes into the next commit.  Once that's happened, it's actually safe to list `public` rather than `public/*` in the `.gitignore` file, because now that Git has a file in the directory, Git is forced to scan the directory.  The entry for `public/.gitignore` will only be *removed* from the index again by an explicit request to remove that entry (`git rm public/.gitignore` or `git rm --cached public/.gitignore`), or by moving to (`git checkout`-ing) an existing commit in which there is no `public/.gitignore` file.  Once the index entry is removed, it's no longer safe to list `public` rather than `public/*`, because Git can go back to its trick of noticing that `public` is a directory *and* is ignored *and* Git has nothing forcing Git to look inside `public`, so that it doesn't look inside and doesn't find `public/.gitignore` and hence doesn't check for the exception.

---

There are of course other ways to do the same thing.  My preference is not to list the directory at all in the top level: instead, *inside* the `public` directory, create a `.gitignore` file with the contents:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Git will then have to scan the `public` directory for files, since it's not ignored; that directory then has a `.gitignore` file, and that `.gitignore` file says: *ignore everything here, except for `.gitignore` here.*  Since Git has already gone inside the directory at this point, and has found a list of all files and sub-directories within that directory, it will check each such file and sub-directory individually against this `.gitignore` and ignore all of them except for `.gitignore` itself.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude files in a sub-directory, append the following to a .gitignore in your base directory:

```
/public/scrpits.min.js
/public/styles.css
/sub-directory/file.whatever
etc...
```

If that's the only item in the folder and you need to keep that folder active, maybe place a blank text file in it